# Calculating scene's children's matrixes without rendering

Tags: three.js

It seems a call to `renderer.render(scene, camera)` is mandatory to get the `matrix` propriety filled in.

For instance, have a scene with a cube :

```
 var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10,10,10);
 var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat)
 mesh.position.set(50, 0 , -50)
 scene.add(mesh)
```

with a call to `renderer.render(scene, camera)`, the `matrix.elements` propriety of this mesh is :

`[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 50, 0, -50, 1]`

and without :

`[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  0, 0,   0, 1]`

It seems only the positions are not set, when comparing the two arrays..

My use case is I only need the matrix of elements. And in order to increase performance, I think getting rid of the render phase, which I presume is the most costly, would be a good thing.

Comment: would it be `scene.updateMatrixWorld()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following two methods, as needed, to update an object's matrix transforms:

```
object.updateMatrix();,
object.updateMatrixWorld();
```

`scene.updateMatrixWorld()` will update the world matrices of the complete scene graph, and it is called for you automatically when you call `renderer.render()`.

Check the source code of these methods so you understand what they are doing.

three.js r.81